# Xml движок (парсер)

Tags: xml, c, c++

Какой Xml движок (парсер) посоветуете? Движок должен быть написан на C или С++. Основные опции:

1. Простой алгоритм разбора ответа.
2. Простой алгоритм создание запроса.
3. Бесплатный.
4. Открытый код.
5. GPL лицензия.
6. Набор примеров использования (samples) идущих в комплекте.

Comment: Поясните, что такое "разбор ответа" и "создание запроса" в контексте XML?
И еще. Насколько я знаю лицензию GPL, она подразумевает бесплатность и открытость кода. Тогда зачем вы говорите об этом еще раз отдельно? Вам действительно нужна именно GPL? Подойдет ли LGPL? или MIT?

Answer (score 1):

Самая стабильная библиотека содержащая в себе большое количество протоколов - [LibXml2](http://xmlsoft.org/). Данная библиотека написана на С, след она кросс платформенная. Идет в открытых исходных кодах. Большое количество опций компиляции, что при ненадобности позволяет отказаться от сторонних зависимостей.

На мой взгляд, может подойти [Tiny XML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml/).

Это легковесная библиотека, в которой имеется лишь базовый функционал xml. Она хорошо подойдет для построения простых xml выражений.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй [Xerces XML Parser](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/), твоим требованиям отвечает, только лицензия - Apache Software License, Version 2.0, а не GPL.

Comment: Данная библиотека очень тяжелая. А Вы ее сами хоть раз использовали?

Comment: Когда я использовал данную библиотеку, я заметил, что у нее слабая совместимость от версии к версии, т.е. на разных релизах она ведет себя по разному. Я бы ее не советовал.

Answer (score 0):

[pugixml](http://pugixml.org/) - легкий, простой и быстрый XML парсер для C++ с поддержкой XPath. Правда, там MIT лицензия.